# Porque é que o Bitmap fica maior ao carregá-lo a partir da pasta res/drawable-mdpi?

Tags: android, bitmap

Desenvolvi uma aplicação em que faço o download de uma imagem JPEG (tamanho 184x274) a partir de um URL. Ao fazer o download a partir do URL obtenho um bitmap de 184x274 pixels, ou seja tem a mesma dimensão que a imagem original. Se a minha imagem original estiver na pasta res/drawable-mdpi e utilizar o seguinte código:

```
Bitmap imageFromRes;
imageFromRes = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imagem);
int hr = imageFromRes.getHeight();
int wr = imageFromRes.getWidth();
```

obtenho hr = 552 e wr=822, ou seja uma dimensão de 552x822 e a imagem fica 3 vezes maior que a imagem original. Porque isso acontece? Obrigado

Comment: Seria possível informar a URL da imagem que você está testando?

Comment: @AndréRibeiro A URL utilizada é esta: http://alunos.deec.uc.pt/~a2008112913/imagem%20lida.jpg

Comment: Essa imagem tem 274x184. É a original?

Comment: @AndréRibeiro Não, eu coloquei a imagem original na pasta res e obtive a largura e a altura da imagem usando o seguinte codigo:    imageFromRes = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imagem);
  int hr = imageFromRes.getHeight();
  int wr = imageFromRes.getWidth();             e obtive um altura de 552 e largura de 822... portanto julgo que estes valores são os correctos da imagem original. Obrigado

Comment: Não entendi. Esse link que você mandou é da imagem *gerada* ou da *original*? Eu queria ver a imagem original pra poder testar.

Comment: Fiz o download do bitmap a partir do URL da imagem, que é a mesma imagem que coloquei na pasta res da minha aplicação. No entanto no bitmap obtido por download a partir do URL obtive uma dimensao de 184x274 e no bitmap obtido a partir da pasta res usando o código que coloquei no comentario anterior obtive 552x822. A imagem na pasta res é a mesma imagem que está nesse URL. Desculpe se não me fiz entender, espero que agora fique explicito :) Obrigado

Comment: Marco, edite sua pergunta e adicione estas informações. Da forma como está escrito lá parece que seu problema é outro totalmente diferente.

Comment: Desculpe, já consegui confirmar que a imagem original tem 184x274! Contudo usando o código para fazer o load do bitmap, a partir da pasta res a imagem fica com 552x822. Mas não sei o porque. Obrigado vou editar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As dimensões retornadas no Android são proporcionais ao *dpi* do aparelho usado.

Para verificar o tamanho original da imagem você pode fazer do seguinte modo:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inScaled = false;
Bitmap imageFromRes = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imagem, opt);
```

Com a opção [`inScaled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inScaled) como `false`, o tamanho retornado é exatamente o tamanho da imagem.